# Can I say: I very like it?

Tags: british-english

My question in the title. Or should I talk `I like it very much` and etc? Just foreigners never said me about this error but my English teacher said. And I want to know what is a true.

Comment: *Very* can modify adjectives, but not verbs.

Comment: Thank you! Just I thought always  that is a normal expression

Comment: You can say "I really like it". I'm not sure why you can do one and not the other.

Comment: [*Really*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/really) can be used as an intensifier.

Comment: Just to add another few bits of entropy to this discussion, it's not at all uncommon to say "I very much like it"; but the word *much* would be required there. And you nevere hear "I much like it" or "I like it much."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a person corrects your English and they are not your teacher and you haven't asked them -- it's rude. If you ask me for a tomato but you wanted a banana, I might tell you the correct names in clearing up the problem -- but otherwise, if you are understood no one should correct you.

*I very like it* should be: **I really like it**. Or, **I like it very much.**

I don't understand why English speakers say the really/very thing, but we do.

Comment: Want to muddy the waters some? Try to explain why _I very like it_ doesn't work, but _I very much like it_ does. :-)

Comment: @J.R. I can't explain it, but would add that here, you'd sound very pompous saying it. I am a Canadian living in Texas and am told I sound like a teacher (meant as a polite but firm insult) or that I "talk fancy." "I very much like it." Sounds more Brit than Am. Would you explain it? I'd love to understand it!

Comment: Willow - I agree it sounds a bit stilted, but it's certainly not ungrammatical. [This excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdKDZ.png) from Dixon's _A Semantic Approach to English Grammar_ touches on this issue some.

Comment: @J.R. clear as mud -- but oh yes, grammatical!